# PyQt5 - When button clicked in one tab, do 'action' in another tab - scope issue

Tags: python-3.x, class, oop, pyqt5

To keep code manageable I've split everything into classes. TabWidget instances are called in Window, tablet classes are called within Tab classes etc.

How can I split functionality/actions into its own class outside of the Window class?

Eg: If I click the Apply button in the top tab widget (tabIn.tablet1.btnApply), how can I programmatically listen for this event and do some action (such as write "Hi") on the bottom tab widget (tabOut.tablet1.textGreeting)? Currently I can do handle this inside Window class, but as my code grows it will become massive, so would like to move to its own class.

I'm very new to OOP and PyQt

[Window Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YFX8S.jpg)

#### Versions:

```
python                 3.7.3
PyQt5                  5.15.4
PyQt5-Qt5              5.15.2
PyQt5-sip              12.8.1
```

#### CODE

```
"""
Initialises Window, Sets out the geometry management, and adds Widgets
"""
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal, pyqtSlot
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (
  QApplication, QGridLayout, QMainWindow, QTableWidgetItem, QWidget
)

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (
  QComboBox, QFormLayout, QHBoxLayout, QVBoxLayout,
  QLabel, QPushButton, QTabWidget, QTableWidget, QWidget
)


class Window(QMainWindow):
    """Create an instance of Window. Sets up main Window"""
    # my_signal = pyqtSignal(int)
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setMinimumSize(1000, 800)
        self.centralWgt = QWidget()  # create central widget
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWgt)  # set central widget
        self.tabIn = InputTab()  # create input tab widget
        self.tabOut = OutputTab()  # create input tab widget
        self.windowLayout()  # set window layout

        # TODO: Move this and "test" to a class to keep Window minimal
        self.tabIn.tablet1.btnApply.clicked.connect(self.test)

    def test(self):
        """
        When tabIn tablet1 btnApply pressed, Do something in tabOut tablet1
        """
        self.tabOut.tablet1.textGreeting.setText(“Hello”)
        print("Here!")

    def windowLayout(self):
        """Handles the main windows layout"""
        self.layout = QGridLayout()
        self.centralWgt.setLayout(self.layout)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.tabIn, 0, 1)  # Add widgets to layout
        self.layout.addWidget(self.tabOut, 1, 1, 2, 1)  # Add widgets to layout
        # Handle window and widget resizing
        self.layout.setColumnStretch(0, 1)
        self.layout.setColumnStretch(1, 1)
        self.layout.setRowStretch(0, 1)
        self.layout.setRowStretch(1, 1)
        self.layout.setRowStretch(2, 1)


# TAB MANAGEMENT


class Tabs(QTabWidget):
    """Tabs master class"""
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.tabs = QTabWidget()  # Initialise Tab Widget
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()  # Define Tab Widget Layout
        self.setLayout(self.layout)  # Set Tab Widget Layout
        self.setStyleSheet('QTabBar { font-size: 12pt;}')  # Set tab title size


class InputTab(Tabs):
    """Creates and sets up the InputTab Class. Inherits from Tab Class"""
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.tablet1 = ItemTablet(QWidget())  # Initialise tablet
        self.tabs.addTab(self.tablet1, "Item Queries")  # Add tablet
        self.layout.addWidget(self.tabs)  # Add tablets to layout


class OutputTab(Tabs):
    """Creates and sets up the OutputTab Class. Inherits from Tab Class"""
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.tablet1 = TableTablet(QWidget())  # Initialise tablet
        self.tabs.addTab(self.tablet1, "Output - Item Table")  # Add tablet
        self.layout.addWidget(self.tabs)  # Add tablets to layout


# TABLET MANAGEMENT #


class Tablets(QTableWidget):
    """The Tablets master class. Contains shared methods, variables"""
    def __init__(self, widget):
        super().__init__()
        self.widget = widget  # set tablet widget as given widget type
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()  # create tablet outer layout
        self.setLayout(self.layout)  # set tablet outer layout
        self.setStyleSheet('font-size: 10pt;')  # Set tablet font size

    def populateForm(self, formFields):
        """Populates a form layout with dict key value pairs"""
        for k, v in formFields.items():
            self.frmLayout.addRow(k, v)  # Add items to tablet form layout

    def stdButtons(self):
        """Adds Apply and Clear buttons to bottom of tablet."""
        self.btnApply = QPushButton(text="Apply")
        self.btnClear = QPushButton(text="Clear")
        self.btnLayout.addWidget(self.btnApply)
        self.btnLayout.addWidget(self.btnClear)

    def stdFormLayout(self):
        """Creates a Form with horizontal buttons at bottom"""
        self.frmLayout = QFormLayout()  # create tablet sublayout
        self.btnLayout = QHBoxLayout()  # create tablet sublayout
        self.layout.addLayout(self.frmLayout)  # set tablet sublayout
        self.layout.addLayout(self.btnLayout)  # set tablet sublayout


class ItemTablet(Tablets):
    """Handles Item Tablet"""
    def __init__(self, widget):
        super().__init__(widget)
        self.stdFormLayout()  # choose stdFormLayout as a sublayout
        self.stdButtons()  # add stdButtons to sublayout
        # create form items
        self.lblItems = QLabel("Item name")
        self.cmbItems = QComboBox()
        self.cmbItems.addItems(["1", "2", "3"])

        # add form items to dict to setup widget associations
        self.formFields = {
            self.lblItems: self.cmbItems,
        }
        self.populateForm(self.formFields)  # add items to form layout


class TableTablet(Tablets, QTableWidget):
    """Handles the output table tablet"""
    def __init__(self, widget):
        super().__init__(widget)
        self.style = "::section{Background-color:lightgray;border-radius:9px;}"
        self.header = self.horizontalHeader()
        self.header.setStyleSheet(self.style)
        self.textGreeting = QLineEdit()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.textGreeting)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication([])
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking. What do you mean with "how can I programmatically listen"? In any case, I have to say, your attempt to "keep the code manageable" has some issues, some of which have priority on the "manageability". First of all, remember that refactoring and "class splitting" should *improve* your code organization and readability (for instance, having 3 separate functions in `Tablets` is pointless). `TableTablet` inherits from two Qt subclasses, Qt doesn't work very well with multiple inheritance, and yours doesn't make a lot of sense anyway. Then, why are you ->

Comment: -> subclassing from QTabWidget in `Tabs` and then create a *new* QTabWidget (`tabs`) in it? And what's the point of the `QWidget()` you create for `ItemTablet` and `TableTablet`? The argument of a widget is intended to be a *parent*, what's the use of having an empty QWidget for that? Before thinking about refactoring (which should be done with care, as it *should be practical*), I suggest you to solve the above issues, which are more important. Besides that, having a "massive" class is not an issue, if done thoughfully, and is sometimes better than having dozens of pointless small classes.

Comment: @musicamante, By listening I mean how can I get a button click event. My example is simplified as In my actual code I have 3 tablets in each tab widget, each with many labels, combo boxes, buttons etc. leaving it in the window class makes the code unmanageable.  What do you mean having 3 functions in Tablets is pointless? Did you read the code? Those functions are used by each tablet class. I think you’re right about inheriting Qwidget being wrong as an argument .

Comment: @musicamante please expand on why you think 3 separate functions in class Tablets is pointless as all inherited classes utilise these functions. 
Subclassing from QTabWidget to extend its functionality, and to use the class as an instance creator (of tablets) to move that code from the Window. How would you suggest I structure my code to handle 2 tabwidgets, that communicate to one another, without having an overextended Window class?

Comment: Unless you really have needs for a *highly* modular implementation, excessive subclassing has more drawbacks than benefits. `stdFormLayout` and `stdButtons` are highly interdependent (so there's little benefit in having in different functions, especially considering that those functions are very simple and are also called only once). As said, you shouldn't be too obsessed with having a "small" main class. Separating object classes is mostly for the benefits of oop: modularity and reusability; if you end up with just a couple of classes that are very similar, then use specialized functions.

Comment: Besides that, I know that you want to expand the QTabWidget, the point is that you're subclassing **and** creating another QTabWidget *inside* it, which is the one that you're actually using. In practice, you're creating two tab widgets for each `Tabs` class, the actual sublass, but there should not be a `self.tabs` object, unless you want a *sub level* of tabs (which shouldn't be implemented like that, in any case).

Comment: I should have explained better, I’m not necessarily looking to make the Window Class smaller, I just need it manageable. Having 3 TabWidgets each with their own tabs and layouts creates a mess of naming each tab and it’s tabs, and it’s layouts. Subclassing is the only way I can think of to solve it. You’re right that those 2 functions should be merged